# Google search results order for same site

Tags: google, seo

When you Google my client's business, the first four results are all their site, but for some reason their homepage is the 4th result. The first three links are to specific pages on the site. Any way to get that homepage appearing above the other pages?

Answer (score 1):

Google will associate the search terms with the content on the page and offpage links. It sounds like you either have more links going to those pages that are top or the fact that your not giving Google the correct siginals and you most likely have the same Title, Meta Desc and H1 on all of those pages.

You should be able to overcome this issue by ensuring or doing the following:

- Google Maps listing
- Google Places Listing
- Use of Citations
- Markup of Schema using LocalBusiness or Organization
- Some links to the homepage
- Perhaps more content on the homepage if its 'thin'
- On page optimisation on the frontpage, ensure that you have H1 with company name, meta description, and title. The deeper pages should not need the company name in any of these elements as this should be revelant to what they are searching.
- Try not to use the company name as much on the deeper pages.